# How to show that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, galois-theory

In Abbot's Understanding Analysis I am asked to show that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is an algebraic number. I have shown that those two are algebraic separately (that was simple), but I can't figure out what to do to show that their sum is algebraic, too. For example, I tried $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^{2}=5+\sqrt{24}$ and then I tried to think of a polynomial of form $ax^2-bx^{0}=0$ e.g. $c(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^{2}-c(5+\sqrt{24})=0$ that would work, but couldn't find the $c$ value that would make $b=c(5+\sqrt{24})$ integer, but couldn't find one. Maybe I can somehow conjecture that the sum of two algebraic numbers must be algebraic, too, but I was wondering if there's a way to find a polynomial to show this. Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. Note that $x^2=2+2\sqrt{6}+3$ and therefore $x^2-5=2\sqrt{6}$. We can square both sides of this equation and obtain $(x^2-5)^2=24$. You should now be able to show that $x$ is an algebraic number (over $\mathbb{Q}$). (In fact, it is instructive to expand this equation and obtain a monic polynomial $p$ of degree $4$ such that $p(x)=0$.)

The following exercises are relevant:

***Example-Based Exercises***:

***Exercise 1***: Prove that the following numbers are algebraic (over $\mathbb{Q}$):

**(a)** $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}$

**(b)** $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{4}$

**(c)** $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}$

The **degree of an algebraic number** $x$ is defined to be the least positive integer $n$ such that there is a monic polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ with $p(x)=0$. Compute the degrees of each of the algebraic numbers above (in **(a)**, **(b)** and **(c)**). Prove that your answer is correct in each case.

***Exercise 2***: Let $p_1,\dots,p_n$ be distinct (positive) prime numbers. Prove that the number $x=\sqrt{p_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{p_n}$ is algebraic. What is the degree of $x$?

***Exercise 3***: Let $x$ be an algebraic number and let $q$ be a rational number. Prove that the degree of $x$ equals the degree of $x+q$.

***Exercise 4***: Let $x=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ for some positive integer $n$. Is $x$ algebraic (over $\mathbb{Q}$)? If not, prove it, and if so find the degree of $x$. (Your answer will depend on $n$.)

***Theoretical Exercises***:

***Exercise 5***: Let $x\in\mathbb{C}$ and define $\mathbb{Q}[x]=\{f(x):f\text{ is a polynomial with rational coefficients}\}$.

**(a)** Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. (Hint (for one direction): if $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and if $a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_nx^n=0$ where $a_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$, show that $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{n-1}\}$ spans $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.)

**(b)** Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a field if $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. (Hint: it suffices to prove that $x$ has a multiplicative inverse. Let $p$ be a monic polynomial of minimal degree (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$) such that $p(x)=0$. Prove that $p(0)\neq 0$ if $x\neq 0$.)

**(c)** Prove that if $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K\subseteq L$ is a tower of fields and if $K$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, $L$ is a finite dimensional $K$-vector space, then $L$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

**(d)** Prove that the sum and product of two algebraic numbers (over $\mathbb{Q}$) is algebraic. (Hint: if $x$ and $y$ are algebraic, use **(c)** to show that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]=\{f(x,y):f\text{ is a polynomial in two variables with rational coefficients}\}$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. **(a)** is relevant.)

***Challenge***: If $x$ and $y$ are algebraic numbers (over $\mathbb{Q}$), can you find an explicit polynomial $p$ with rational coefficients such that $p(x+y)=0$? Can you find an explicit polynomial $q$ with rational coefficients such that $q(xy)=0$?

I hope this helps!

Comment: Dear Amitesh, you missed a $ sign, for \mathbb{Q}. I have edited it. Hope that isn't a concern

Comment: @Chandru: Dear Chandru, absolutely not. Thank you very much for your edit!

Comment: @Amitesh Datta Hi, this is sort of a side comment really, but is your mentor Elizabeth Ormerod? Just wandering, she mentioned of you to me once when I met her. It would be interesting to meet you at university one day (Sorry I had to say this here).

Comment: @D Lim: Actually, no but I do know her well (she supervised me for an ASC on finite group theory last semester). My mentor is James Borger. Anyway, I would be happy to meet you one day; unfortunately, I am not in Canberra at the moment. I will be in Canberra on July 26th. You could send me an email; my email address is amiteshdatta@gmail.com.

Comment: An amazing answer Amitesh, thank you. One question, what do you mean when you say "Over Q?" I don't know what people mean when in math they say "bla bla bla over R/Q/etc." especially when talking about fields. Does it mean we take the coefficients of the polynomials be only rational numbers? Thanks!

Comment: @confused Thanks for the kind words! Yes, a polynomial "over $\mathbb{Q}$" is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. Similarly, a complex number $x$ is algebraic "over $\mathbb{Q}$" if there is a polynomial $p$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $p(x)=0$ etc.

Answer (score 23):

We show how to exploit *symmetries* to produce an answer. Although we only deal with the specific question, we deal with it in a structured way that at least hints at generalization.

Note that  $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is the solution  of $x-(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=0$. 
But  $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are friends and like to travel in pairs, as do $\sqrt{3}$ and $-\sqrt{3}$.

In acknowledgement of this, let
$$P(x)=(x-(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}))(x-(-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}))(x-(-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}))(x-(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})).$$

Intuitively speaking at least, $P(x)$ should have integer coefficients.  Why? First observe that the coefficients of a polynomial  are *symmetric functions* of the roots.

Now *imagine* "simplifying" $P(x)$.  Each  coefficient of $P(x)$ must be of the shape 
$$A+B\sqrt{2}+ C\sqrt{3} + D\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3},$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are integers.  But this expression must remain unchanged if we replace $\sqrt{2}$ by $-\sqrt{2}$ and/or $\sqrt{3}$ by $-\sqrt{3}$, so we *should* have $B=C=D=0$.  Thus every coefficient of $P(x)$ should be an integer.

Until we back up this kind of intuition with general theorems, our discussion  has a speculative character.  However, in this case, we can easily multiply out $P(x)$ and check directly that it has integer coefficients. The product of the first two terms is $x^2-2\sqrt{3}\,x+1$, and the product of the next two terms is $x^2+2\sqrt{3}\,x +1$.
Thus
$$P(x)=x^4-10x^2+1,$$
and our intuition has been fully verified.

**Comment**: All the speculative elements above can be put on a firm foundation. With the proper theoretical background in place, we would not have needed to compute at all.  "Symmetries" play a central role in the study of algebraic numbers.  This was a key insight of Lagrange, which led ultimately to the breakthroughs by Abel and Galois.

Answer (score 12):

Call $x= \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$, then by your equation we have $$x^{2} = 5 +\sqrt{24} \Longrightarrow (x^{2}-5)^{2}=24$$

For a proof of sum of $2$ algebraic numbers being algebraic, please see:

- http://arcsecond.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/the-sum-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic/

Answer (score 11):

It is true that the sum and product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic. Thus, the algebraic numbers form a field.

The easiest way to see this is, however, indirect. I will assume you know some linear algebra over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rational numbers, and for simplicity we shall assume that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{C}$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. By $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ we mean the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}$ containing both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$. It should be fairly obvious that $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ consists of all finite sums of the form $c_0 + c_1 \alpha + \cdots + c_r \alpha^r$, for all $r \in \mathbb{N}$, and so we see that $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots \}$ is a spanning set. Now, suppose $\alpha$ is algebraic. Then $\alpha$ satisfies a polynomial, so in fact there is a finite number $n$ so that $\{ 1, \alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{n-1} \}$ is a *basis* for $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Conversely, if $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is finite-dimensional, then any $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ must be algebraic: since, for $n$ large enough, $\{ 1, x, \ldots, x^n \}$ will not be linearly independent, and we will be able to obtain a non-trivial equation which relates the powers of $x$, thus a witness for the algebraicity of $x$. So we have connected algebraicity with finite-dimensionality.

Now, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two algebraic numbers. By $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha, \beta]$ we mean the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ *and* $\alpha$ *and* $\beta$. But any such ring must contain $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$, so if we can show $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha, \beta]$ is finite-dimensional then we are done. But it has to be: we know any element of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ can be written as a finite sum of powers of $\alpha$ and similarly for $\beta$, thus, if $\{ 1, \alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{n-1} \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $\{ 1, \beta, \ldots, \beta^{m-1} \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$, $\{ \alpha^a \beta^b : 0 \le a < n, 0 \le b < m \}$ must be a spanning set for $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha, \beta]$. Thus the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha, \beta]$ is at most the product of the dimensions of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$, and in particular $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$ are algebraic.

The only thing left to do is to show that $1 / \alpha$ is algebraic if $\alpha$ is algebraic and non-zero, but this is straightforward enough: given a polynomial $\alpha$ satisfies, we can manipulate it to find a polynomial $1 / \alpha$ satisfies. (Exercise for the reader!)

Comment: There is another proof that every non-zero element in $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is invertible and it too uses linear algebra: Consider the map $x \mapsto ax$ on $\mathbb{Q}(a)$. This map is linear and has trivial kernel, since otherwise $1,a,\dotsc,a^{n-1}$ would be linearly dependant—contradicting that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ is $n$. We conclude that $a$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and the invertability of all other non-zero elements follows. You can read a bit more detail at this page: http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/galois.html

Comment: PS: Isn't it customary to write "$K(a)$ for $K$ with $a$ adjoined and $K[a]$ for the ring of polynomials in one variable over $K$?

Comment: @kahen: $K(a)$ is the smallest *field* containing $K$ and $a$, and I didn't want to muddy things.

Answer (score 10):

You should just proceed until you obtain $(x^2-5)^2 = 24$.

Answer (score 10):

Note $\rm\ \alpha = \sqrt{2}\:+\sqrt{3}\in F = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\:.\:$ But $\rm\:F = \mathbb Q\langle1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\rangle\:$ is a $\rm\:\mathbb Q$-vector space of dimension $4\:,\:$ so the $\:5\:$ elts $\:1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4$ are $\rm\:\mathbb Q$-linearly dependent. Thus $\rm\:f(\alpha) = 0\:$ for some $\rm\:0 \ne f(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]\:$ of degree $\le 4\:.\:$ This proof by *dimension* works generally - see Zhen's answer.

Comment: My answer (above) also discusses the method of "proof by dimension" (as an exercise) ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a polynomial, obviously using total symmetry:

$$(x-\sqrt{2})(x-\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$$

Expand to get

$$x^8 - 15 x^6 + 57 x^4 - 65 x^2 + 6$$

This is a polynomial with integer coefficients whose zeros are, among else, $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ by the factorization given above.

Comment: You don't need the factors with the single roots. $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ has  degree $4$. After fixing this, we arrive at the answer by André Nicolas above posted almost 13 years ago.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If you would not comment, you could not stay alive I guess.