# How to show $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ is algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

How to show $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ is algebraic? Is there a way I can do this without trial and error? Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/how-to-show-that-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-algebraic  see this

Comment: I think you mean algebraic in $\mathbb Q$... if $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$ is a root, so does $\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2$, $-\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$, $-\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2$. Can you find the polynomial?

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I did not see the previous question while searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

$$r=\sqrt2+\sqrt3\implies r^2-2\sqrt2\,r+2=3\implies r^4-2r^2+1=8r^2\iff r^4-10r^2+1=0$$

so that element is a root of

$$x^4-10x^2+1\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$$

Answer (score 2):

Write $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$. So $\sqrt{2}=x-\sqrt{3}$. Now we square $x^2-2x\sqrt{3}+3=2$ which rewrites as $x^2+1=2x\sqrt{3}$. Square again to get

$$x^4+2x^2+1=12x^2\iff x^4-10x^2+1=0$$