# Rationalizing General Denominators

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, galois-theory, extension-field, radicals

I've read on several answers how to rationalize a fraction of the form
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{1}} + \dots +\sqrt{a_{n}}}
$$
by multiplying top and bottom by the numbers
$$\varepsilon_{1}\sqrt{a_{1}} + \dots +\varepsilon_{n}\sqrt{a_{n}},$$
where $\varepsilon_{i} \in \left\{1,-1\right\}$, avoiding the current denominator, that is, avoiding the number that corresponds to $\varepsilon_{i} = 1$, for all $i$. In fact, it is possible to do it restricting ourselves to the family
$$\sqrt{a_{1}} + \varepsilon_{2}\sqrt{a_{2}} + \dots +\varepsilon_{n}\sqrt{a_{n}},$$
that is, ignoring the terms where $\varepsilon_{1} = -1$. My questions are the following ones:

1. Is there a way of doing it involving less products (for n large)?
2. Can somebody give me a book or reference that deals with the more general case
   $$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{a_{1}} + \dots +\sqrt[m]{a_{n}}}
   $$
   or, more generally,
   $$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt[m_{1}]{a_{1}} + \dots +\sqrt[m_{n}]{a_{n}}},
   $$
   including an **explicit algorithm** and (if possible) a proof of its correctness?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Is there a way of doing it involving less products (for n large)?" In general, no unless you have a particular case where some intermediate products of roots give a rational number... In fact, these questions should be settled in the advanced framework of "fields extensions", and consider the "algorithmic approach" in a second step.

Comment: Note: In math, despite what your school teachers may have said, denominators don't necessarily have to be free of radicals.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha$ be the denominator. What you desire is the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)) of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$, which is the lowest degree polynomial $P$ with rational coefficients where

$$P(\alpha)=0$$

which means

$$\frac1\alpha=\frac{P(0)-P(\alpha)}{P(0)\alpha}=Q(\alpha)$$

is a polynomial in $\alpha$ and involves the minimum amount of products. There are many methods for finding such polynomials. If you wish you can even ask [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+of+sqrt%282%29%2Bcbrt%283%29).

The particular case where only square roots appear in the denominator can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50366/272831), where you can see several other methods, and generalizes to higher order radicals via using $\varepsilon_i$ being [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity). With some more theory, you will find that this factorization is minimal *unless* the products of powers of the terms are related e.g. $\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9$ has degree $3$ instead of degree $9$ (compare [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+of+cbrt%283%29%2Bcbrt%289%29) to [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+of+cbrt%283%29%2Bcbrt%282%29)).

As an example, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]3$ is

$$P(x)=x^6-6x^4-6x^3+12x^2-36x+1$$

which gives us the rationalization

$$\frac1{\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]3}=\frac1\alpha=36-12\alpha+6\alpha^2+6\alpha^3-\alpha^5$$

leaving expansion of the RHS (if it's what you want) to the reader.